How do I truncate the datalabels in the Highcharts Stacked bar so that they stay within their correct color stacks and not overflow into the next?
I have tried to create a bar chart using highcharts and want the labels to stay within the color stacks and truncate with an ellipsis (...) if it overflows
I have tried multiple options using the Highcharts keywords for datalabels
align: 'centre',
overflow: 'none',
verticalAlign: 'middle',
inside: true,
crop: 'true',
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0.1,
            groupPadding: 0.05,
            pointWidth: 30,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'centre',
                overflow: 'none',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                inside: true,
                crop: 'true',
                formatter: function () {
                    const pointValue = this.y as number;
                    const stackTotal = this.total as number;
                    const comparisonValue = this.point?.comparisonValue || 0;
                    const changePercent = comparisonValue
                        ? ((pointValue - comparisonValue) / comparisonValue) * 100
                        : 0;
                    const percentageOfTotal = stackTotal
                        ? ((pointValue / stackTotal) * 100).toFixed(1)
                        : 0;

                    const fullLabel = `${formatNumber(pointValue, numberFormat)} | ${changePercent.toFixed(2)}% vs. ${comparisonMeasureName} | ${percentageOfTotal}% of Ttl.`;
                    return fullLabel;
                },
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'optimo-plain, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                    fontWeight: '500',
                    color: '#5e5e5e',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    textOutline: '1.6px white',
                    textShadow: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px 0px 2px',
                },
            },

None these seem to help

TL;DR: Set the style.width option to match the width of a bar when using the ellipsis text overflow property.
If you'd like to read more:
To enable text ellipsis, set the textOverflow property to "ellipsis". The tricky part is ensuring that the label takes up as much space as possible on the bar without overflowing.
To achieve this, you should iterate through all the points in the chart.events.load function. For each point, update the dataLabel.style.width to match the width of the bar.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/abcqzn1d/
Code:
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    events: {
      load: function () {
        const chart = this
        chart.series.forEach(function (series) {
          series.data.forEach(function (point) {
            const pointWidth = point.shapeArgs.height - 5
            point.update(
              {
                dataLabels: {
                  style: {
                    width: `${pointWidth}px`,
                  },
                },
              },
              false,
            )
          })
        })

        chart.redraw()
      },
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: "normal",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true,
        style: {
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          overflow: "hidden",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
        },
        formatter: function () {
          return "Lorem Ipsum is simply "
        },
      },
    },
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 3],
    },
    {
      data: [2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 3],
    },
    {
      data: [2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 3],
    },
  ],
})

